# rmarkdown running child chunks from inside RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I've been moving some of the code for a report I'm writing to child .rmd files. I want to run these chunks by clicking on the green arrow (top right):

[image]

But this doesn't work in RStudio, is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: At least knitting the thing works fine?

Comment: indeed, but testing it locally before knitting is proving quite a pain!

Comment: True. would be a nice feature, you should request it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has not been implemented in RStudio yet, and probably won't be for some time.

However, you can write your R code in a separate file, reference it in R Markdown chunks, and execute those chunks interactively in RStudio. The way to do this is with knitr's code externalization feature. You can read about how to use it in R Markdown notebooks here:

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html#executing_code (scroll down a bit to *Executing External Chunks*)

More on code externalization with knitr here:

https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/

Comment: thanks Jonathan, I'll add a feature request and stick to executing external chunks

Comment: @pluke wonder if anything has happened on this during the last 5 years.

Comment: Five months I think? I put in a feature request, will have to check to see its status and link here

Comment: the request is now here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/making-child-code-chunks-execute-by-clicking-run-current-chunk/12907